# How should I set a custom style on a object that is a gwt component?

Tags: java, html, css, gwt, web-development-server

I am using Java (Eclipse) and for the web development I use gwt. The object that I want to change (`loader`) has a default font-size. It also has a method named `setHtml(String)`. I have almst no knowledge on on HTML and CSS and how should I integrate such files in java code. I've been told that I should write something like:
`loader.setHTML("<span class = 'something>'" +.... )`
What this something should be? Does it have to be an .css file and just the path to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do that.

First, you can define the rule in CSS. You do need to learn HTML and CSS for web development - no way around that.

Second, you can set a particular CSS property directly in your code:

```
loader.getElement().getStyle().setFontSize(24, Unit.PX);
```

Comment: `loader.getElement().getStyle().setFontSize(24, Unit.PX);` doesn't work. On FireBug it shows that the element still inherit the font size of the loader component (defined in gwt). I will try the other way.

Comment: This means that this widget gets a style set later in your code, or your CSS file has a rule that overrides the font size. For example, you may have a rule that sets the font size on a child element within a loader element.

Comment: I have one more question. For the first way, you meant something like this `loader.setHtml("<span font-size=\"18px'" + messages.loaderText() + "</span>");` right?

Comment: It should be `style="font-size:18px"`, but better to use CSS classes.